# Show that $ F_{7}[i]=\{a+bi : a,b \in F_{7} \}$ is a field but that $F_5[i]$ is not

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

> (i) Show that $ F_{7}[i]=\{a+bi : a,b \in F_{7} \}$ is a field with 49 elements.
>
> (ii) Show that $ F_{5}[i] =\{a+bi : a,b \in F_{5} \} $ is not a field.

My answer: (i) I  have shown that $ F_{7}[i] $ has 49 elements in the following way: Since $a$ has $7$ choices and for each of these choices $b$  has $7$ choices, we have $7\cdot 7=49$ choices in total.   So $ F_{7}[i]  $ has $49$ elements. But now how can I be sure that $ F_{7}[i] $ is a field?

Please help me the last part and hints of part (ii) if possible

Comment: With low level tools (no theory of quotient rings of polynomial rings et cetera) you can do the following. For (i) you should check that $a^2+b^2$ is divisible by $7$ only when both $a$ and $b$ are. This implies that you find inverses of elements of $F_7[i]$ much the same way you find inverses of complex numbers. For (ii) calculate $(2+i)(2-i)$. Since that may be too easy you can also check that it is possible for $a^2+b^2$ to be divisible by five even though neither $a$ nor $b$ is. If you understand the connection, then I predict that you will do relatively well :-)

Answer (score 6):

$$F_7[i] \cong \frac{F_7[x]}{(x^2+1)}$$

Therefore $F_7[i]$ will be a field if and only if $x^2+1$ is irreducible over $F_7$. Since it is a quadratic, you only need to check that it has no roots.

For $F_5[i]$, note that $x^2+1$ is $\textbf{not}$ irreducible over $F_5$.

Comment: I'm not sure of what means $i$ in $F_5[i]$. If it is the field extension of $F_5$ containing $\sqrt{-1}$ then $2^2 = -1$ in $F_5$ therefore $F_5[i] = F_5$ (which is a field). But $F_5[i] = F_5[x]/(x^2+1)$ or $F_5[i] = \mathbb{Z}[i]/(5)$ seems to be the definition the OP is using. Do you see what I mean ?

Comment: That is a good point. It isn't great notation. I would prefer not to call the ring in part $ii)$, $F_5[i]$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** It's true that $F_7[i]$ has $49$ elements, but not all rings with $49$ elements are fields! (For example, consider the direct product $F_7 \times F_7$.) One way to proceed is as follows. By $F_7[i]$ one presumably means the quotient $F_7[x] / \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle$, where $i$ just denotes the image of $x$ under the quotient $F_7[x] \to F_7[x] / \langle x^2 + 1\rangle$. So, if you can show that $x^2 + 1$ is irreducible in $F_7[x]$, the ideal $\langle x^2 + 1 \rangle$ is maximal.

What goes wrong if we try to carry out the same procedure with $F_5[i]$?